# What do the 3 ICMP phases in Prometheus' blackbox exporter mean?

Tags: prometheus, icmp, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

There are 3 phases of ICMP in Prometheus while we are probing data via BlackBox exporter.

1. resolve
2. rtt
3. setup

What is the purpose of each of these phases?

Here is an example dataset:

```
probe_icmp_duration_seconds{phase="resolve"} 1.4725e-05
probe_icmp_duration_seconds{phase="rtt"} 0.000237673   
probe_icmp_duration_seconds{phase="setup"} 0.000140214
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For most internet connections, there is often multiple phases of connecting to a remote service that includes steps like this.  For Prometheus / blackbox the steps are:

1. Resolve the DNS name (or IP address) into an IP address that can be used to send the ICMP echo request (ping) to.  This has some latency depending on the DNS service being used, caching, etc. Hence the `probe_icmp_duration_seconds` value for `phase="resolve"` is non-zero, but often small if the DNS resolver has cached the answer already.
2. There is a socket setup required for sending the outbound request.  The length of time to measure this setup process is recorded in the `phase="setup"` value.
3. Finally, the value most people actually want to measure is the response time between the point where the outgoing ICMP echo request was sent and the point at which the response is received.  This is the `phase="rtt"` value.